# Attributes comparison

Tags: qgis, csv

Is there a way to compare two attributes which can not be related spatially?
For example: I have .CSV file that has names of roads only, no coordinate, no geometry just names, and .SHP that contains the spatial info of those roads as well as their names. Can I compare the two files somehow to make sure the names in the .SHP are the same as the ones in the .CSV?
I'm looking for a method to do this comparison using QGIS or FME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the CSV to QGIS (doens't need geometry or coordinates to do this) then you could use the `Vector general > Join attributes by field value` tool in the Processing Toolbox to join the SHP and the CSV by road name. Wherever it doesn't work is where you need to correct one or the other.